# Закрытие блока при клике вне него

Tags: javascript

Есть блок

```
 <div class="wallets-deposit" id="myModal">
                    <div class="wallets-deposit__inner" >
                        <div class="wallets__p-title">
                            <h5>Withdrawal</h5>
                            <div>Available: <span id="span_in_title_withdrawal"></span></div>
                                <div class="fragment" id="cancel"> <span class="closebtn" style="position: relative; bottom:auto; right: 10px" >&times;</span></div>
                        </div>
```

Нужно его закрывать, если я кликаю вне него, вот код скрытия

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Блок скрывает, но фон позади остается затемненным, и кликнуть никуда нельзя